# Loading Javascript with C# Console Application

Tags: c#, web-scraping, web-crawler, console-application, html-agility-pack

I am currently using htmlAgilityPack for some web scraping, however I've encountered a website that has script tags and I am unable to load it for scraping. I have little experience with web and am unsure how to properly load the webpage and convert back to something htmlAgility can parse.

Pretty much, when I inspect element in chrome, there is a table, but the htmlAgilityPack reads a script tag.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: There are already plenty questions about "scraping dynamic pages"... make sure to search and show which approaches you've tried and how they did not work for your case.

Comment: All of those approaches don't work with console application, which I stated I was using.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+scraping+dynamic+pages+javascript provides answers with both options... Using Google or Bing may be better over whatever search engine you are using...

Comment: Thank you. Those methods worked for several sites containing Javascript, but on some it does not work. Here is how i init:

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems too. It is very annoying that their is not one unified method of doing on all websites in a C# console.

However depending on the site you are looking at there may be some information in meta tags in the head section of the html. When I was making an application to get Youtube Subscription count I found it had the count in a meta tag (I assume this information is here for the scripts to use). This may be similar for the web page you are scraping.

To do this I first added a

```
document.save(//put a link to where the html file needs to go)
```

then I opened the html document in Google Chrome, opened up dev tools and did a search for "Subscriptions" (You can replace this for whatever you are looking for). Hopefully depending on the website you are scraping there may be a tag with some info in it for you.

Good Luck! :)